# Microsoft Graph API Sites search returns deleted sites

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I use the Microsoft Graph API `/sites?search=*` endpoint, I get very old *deleted* sites returned. When I then try to access these sites I get a 404 error.

Note: Some of these sites are not in the SharePoint admin 'Deleted Sites' list either.

So my questions are:

1. Is this (returning deleted sites) expected?
2. Is there a way to exclude deleted sites from search results?